# Need help understanding urdf and tf

Tags: ros, navigation, urdf, tutorials, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've worked through the tutorials on urdf and am working through tf. I have created a urdf for my physical robot. I am striving to get my robot set up to use the Nav stack and somehow had in my mind that the urdf is required and a step towards setting up the transforms for the robot, but if I read that somewhere I cannot now find it and am having a hard time getting my head wrapped around this. I understand why I need transforms, I'm starting to understand how to write the code for the transforms, I am quite confident in my abilities writing a urdf, but I don't see where, if anywhere, the two come together. Do I even need a urdf for a physical robot? I feel I am missing a big BIG part of the picture here and could use a good explanation or at least a nudge in the right direction.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114151/need-help-understanding-urdf-and-tf/) by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2013-12-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd suggest looking at [robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on 2014-01-27**:
 yup. Figured that one out about two weeks ago, just forgot to come back and close out the question. Thanks for the help though!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-01-27**:
Thanks, marking the question with the checkbox is enough. It implicitly closes the question.